# implement a tree that will fit on two column page structure and permit multiline nodes

Tags: trees

I have a paper formatted like [this one](http://people.csail.mit.edu/tommi/papers/Lei-ACL14.pdf), i.e. two columns of text per page.

I've been trying to make a tree structure to fit inside of one column, but so far I've been unable to make it work.

There are resources about how to make tree structures using tikz, [this one](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=20072) for instance, or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/branch-tree-latex). But so far I've been unsuccessful in adapting those solutions to fit my current situation.

I wrote out by hand how I need the tree to look. It's important that the first node be able to spread out across two lines, using, I guess, `//` or `/newline`.

Thus far I have this:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\caption{An illustration of a simple delete operation. \label{fig:simple}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}, scale=0.6,transform shape]
    \node {\footnotesize educated at( Bush, University of Texas at Austin)}
    child
    {
        %node [treenode] {$Y$ \\ 50} 
        child
        {
            %node [treenode] {$Z$ \\ 40} 
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S1$ \\ 30}
                child
                {
                    node {\\60} 
                }
                {
                    node {\\60} 
                }
            }
            child
            {
                {
                    node {\\60} 
                }
                {
                    node {\\60} 
                } 
            }
        }
        child[edge from parent path ={(\tikzparentnode.-50) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
        {
            node [subtree,yshift=0.4cm] (a) {}   % delay the text till later
        }
    }
    child[edge from parent path ={(\tikzparentnode.-30) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
    {
        node [subtree,yshift=0.4cm] (b) {}       % delay the text till later
    }
;
% ------------------------------------------------ put the text into subtree nodes
\node[align=center,yshift=0.1cm] at (a) {$Z$\\200};
\node[align=center,yshift=0.1cm] at (b) {$Z$\\200};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

and these packages:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning}
```

This is ideally how it would look:

[image]

Comment: Please: give us a complete, small document we can copy-paste-compile to see the problem. Fragments of code can be useful to explain things, but a complete, minimal example is really essential.

Comment: What's `treenode`?

Comment: This question is a near-duplicate of the [more recent one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241204/42880) asked by the same user. That one has been answered.

Comment: @JasonZentz Shouldn't have wasted my time...

Comment: @cfr, yeah, sorry -- I didn't see this earlier question until after I had answered the other one. I guess technically this question had a `tikz` MWE and the other one had a `qtree` MWE, but the same problems arise either way and are best dealt with using `forest`.

Comment: @JasonZentz It is not *your* fault. I didn't realise the other question was essentially a duplicate. (The MWE looked different and that one already had a `forest` answer so I didn't pay very close attention ;).) But people should not ask the same question twice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `forest` which produces especially compact trees.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest,kantlipsum}
\forestset{% adapted from page 52
  nice empty nodes/.style={
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={
            anchor=north
          }
        }
      }{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-2]
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\caption{An illustration of a simple delete operation. \label{fig:simple}}

    \begin{forest}
      nice empty nodes,
      for tree={
        align=center,
        parent anchor=south,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, fill, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) circle (1.5pt) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        }
      }
      [\textsc{data representation}\\{\footnotesize educated at (Bush, University of Texas at Austin)}
        [
          [Something\\here
          ]
          [Something\\else
          ]
        ]
        [
          [, tier=tier 1
            [
              [Q value]
              [English]
            ]
            [
              [Q value]
              [English]
            ]
          ]
          [
            [P value, tier=tier 1]
            [English]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}

\end{figure}
\kant[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: tree]